# Loading manually created object to spring context

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have an object created using a `new` operator. Is there a way, in Spring, to load this object in the Spring application context?

I did some research but could not find a working solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

- If you are creating an object after Spring application has started and you want to register it as bean with spring, you can do it. ie. run time only you will know how it will be created or that object is created by a external framework you don't have control over. I just can't remember the frameworks, there are frameworks that used this facility.

```
     //Get hold of application context, you can autowire it
     ConfigurableApplicationContext context;
            
     ServiceX servicex = //This object was created outside spring framework.

     //Register it with spring
     context.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("servicex", servicex);

     //Above bean is now available as part of spring application context.
```

Comment: Thanks . this is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Spring's `@Configuration` class and define `@Bean` method in there. In that method, create your custom `new` object and make sure you return that object.

```
@Bean
public YourType methodName() {
    //code here..
    return new YourType();
}
```

Put this into your `@Configuration` class and object returned by `return new YourType();` will be registered into your Spring Context.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but in my case I am loading the class from an external folder at runtime and creating object using Jar class loader i.e I already have the object created . Can i put this object in the spring context?

Comment: What difference does that make? Just return your object that you created from the new operator to a method with the @Bean annotation.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you obtain your object, do you unmarshal it from REST/XML, do you receive it via network, from file I/O, or just whatsoever.. that's why I explicitly named my exemplifying class `YourType`. It can be anything you wish.